# Error MySQL Creating Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm getting an odd error every time I try to create one UPDATE trigger into one of my tables...

## The Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_data_nascimento BEFORE UPDATE ON pfi_pessoa_fisica
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     IF OLD.date_of_birth = '0000-00-00' THEN
     SET NEW.date_of_birth = NULL;
     END IF;
  END;
```

And the error:

> Error SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using delimiter

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_data_nascimento BEFORE UPDATE ON abc_table
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     IF OLD.date_of_birth = '0000-00-00' THEN
        SET NEW.date_of_birth = NULL;
     END IF;
  END
```

If you are executing it in PHPMyAdmin then set the delimiter to # or something else. And then execute it will work fine I have tested it with above code.